# Error al iniciar nginx

Tags: nginx

Hola a todos acabé de instalar nginx en windows 10 y me sale este log al intentar abrirlo y no funciona

> 2016/07/04 17:34:00 [emerg] 11100#984: CreateFile()
>   "C:\Users\Nicolás\Downloads\Compressed\nginx-1.10.1/conf/nginx.conf"
>   failed (1113: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the
>   target multi-byte code page)

Intente cambiar los puertos pero al parecer es un problema con los juegos de caracteres y no se que hacer :(

Estuve navegando en el foro de inglés pero no encuentro una respuesta para solucionar mi falla.

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Actualizo: esto pasa con cualquier versión

Comment: Muchas gracias @toledano si era por el bendito acento jejeje la puse en C:

Un saludo !

Comment: Voy a poner el comentario como respuesta, para que puedas marcarla como aceptada.

Comment: Listo marcada :) gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso se debe a que en la ruta en la que estás ubicando tu archivo de configuración hay acentos. Con toda seguridad la codificación de Windows no es compatible con la que utiliza Nginx.

Cambia las rutas, sobre todo las de los archivos de registro o *logs* a una que sea diferente de `Nicolás`. Por ejemplo,

```
c:/temp/
```

Reinicia tu servidor después de cualquier cambio.